# SFMC Automation File transfer splits a single row into multiple lines due to line feed char

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract, character-encoding

I have an issue with a DE data extract followed by a Transfer file activity that splits a single row into multiple lines on the file transfer.

Expecting 1 row as below":

`"1","5717167","357099999","1125","","xxxi.tolxxx@yopmail.com","2023-08-01 05:41:00","","","XXX","XXXXXReceived_SMSE","","","B08A78A1-53E7-4A64-8D67-07DC2108B45B","SMS","61424999999","D","We've received your payment for Transfer ID: xxxxx. Head to https://login.xxx.com for more information. Any Questions? Call 123","4000","Delivered to handset"`

Instead get 3 rows:

`"1","5717167","357099999","1125","","xxxi.tolxxx@yopmail.com","2023-08-01 05:41:00","","","XXX","XXXXXReceived_SMSE","","","B08A78A1-53E7-4A64-8D67-07DC2108B45B","SMS","61424999999","D","We've received your payment for Transfer ID: xxxxx.`

`Head to https://login.xxx.com for more information.`

`Any Questions? Call 123","4000","Delivered to handset"`

I have checked this post : [Problem with CSV file format from Marketing Cloud SFTP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294312/problem-with-csv-file-format-from-marketing-cloud-sftp) and using the 'Replace' function in the SQL query to substitute space for CR/LF works.

But when I tried the other suggestion to use File convert (Data Extract activity) to UTF8 following the Data extract, it does not work. The file gets truncated after the 1st CR/LF char (I get 5 lines instead of the 40K+ lines in the DE). I also tried the UTF-16 to UTF-8 encoding as a subsequent data extract but same result.

Do I need to replace the CR/LF with space or is there an alternative to transfer with the CR/LF char without splitting into multiple lines?

Cheers
Sam

Comment: why can't you use the sql solution that works for you, as you say? From what I gather, the other suggestion you mentioned wasn't verified to work by the person who answered, so not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that is the solution we are going with now - strip out all line breaks before the file transfer